# preg_replace only first number in string

Tags: php, string, numbers, preg-replace, increment

First of all: I'm very bad with regular expressions, the ones I already have here I found on the net.

I want to increment the first number in a string,  e.g. `$teststring = "abcd1234efgh56";`

I have already found the following:

```
preg_replace( "|(\d+)|e", "$1+1", $teststring);
```

will result in `abcd1235efgh57`

```
preg_replace( "|(\d+)(?!.*\d)|e", "$1+1", $teststring);
```

will result in `abcd1234efgh57`

but how do I increment ONLY the first number (1234 in the example) while leaving the rest of the string as is?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out the docs: [php.net manual on preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php)

use the fourth parameter to limit the number of replaces

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`preg_replace('/([^0-9]*)(\d+)(.*)/e', '"$1" . ($2+2) . "$3"' , $str, 1);`

This would match all non-numeric characters (if any) before the first number as `$1`, the first number as `$2`, and all following characters (if any) as `$3`.

It then outputs the string with `2` added to the first number (you can change `$2+2` to `$2+NUMBER`).

The final parameter `1` in the function is limiting the repeats to 1 time only...

Answer (score 0):

The optional fourth parameter of preg_replace is limit :

preg_replace($search , $replace, $subject, $limit)

You can put 1 for your case..

it will give you

$teststring = 'abcd1235efgh56'

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
preg_replace('/^([^0-9]+)?([0-9]+)([^0-9]+)?/', "$2+1", $teststring);
```

Comment: This will only work if there are exactly two numbers in the string.

Comment: Just tested it and it works with 1 or more numbers in the string

Comment: Ahh, never mind. I was confused by the unnecessary `[^0-9]+`.

Comment: I just tried it, the output was `1234+156`. That's not even close to right.